# SSL certificate exception in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

and thanks in advance for your help or any tip that could get me out of here.

I work on a Java EE app with a JBoss server and an Apache. I'm not really familiar with SSL connections and certificates, I understand the basic, but I have to deal with it.
So on my local configuration (**localhost**) I have my connection certificate configured on JBoss and Apache, and a **USER_DEV.P12** file, which I import in my certificates in Firefox.
I have the same configuration on a distant test server (**test-server**), and a **USER_TEST.P12** which I also import in Firefox.

When I access `https://localhost/` or `https://test-server/` Firefox asks me to add an exception, which is normal. After that, I select the appropriated user certificate, and can use my application normally. 
But for the second (let's say `https://test-server/`), Firefox rises me a `sec_error_reused_issuer_and_serial` error. Of course I googled it and founded the [Mozilla help](http://support.mozilla.com/en/kb/Certificate+contains+the+same+serial+number+as+another+certificate), So when I delete the "server" in my certificate manager, I can access again my second domain, but the same problem occurs for the first one.

To shorten the problem, my 2 client/server certificate couples are OK but I can't have 2 certificate exceptions at the same time in Firefox for my 2 different servers/users, even though the names, server address, and MD5 are different. I notified the serial is the same (01), but it's working on my colleague's computer. So am I doing something wrong? Do I have to deal with it manually each time (or with Firefox profiles)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you use self-signed certs and they use the same serial number. You have a few solutions,

1. Re-sign the certificates on the same machine using the same tool. Most tools will bump up the serial number for each signing and you will get different serial number.
2. Make your own CA and sign the 2 certs with the same CA. This way Firefox only needs to import one CA.

Comment: You're right, my certs are self-signed. The first solution worked. Thanks for your help (Btw, I use OpenSSL to create server key, CA and sign my cert, and keytool to manage my keystore).

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I found that deleting the cert*.db files in C:\Users[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[myprofile]

fixed the issue. I have no idea if this has any knock-on effects as Firefox is not my primary browser I just needed to debug something that was not working in Firefox.

Comment: What an "amazing" browser... Your answer should be accepted widely. To me, I have no time to debug which certificates is which. Deleting the "suspected" certificate in firefox also don't make it work. Edge and Chrome all are working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same error message under different circumstances, but googling the error message leads me here. I access IPMI remote management controllers for blade servers installed at a remote facility by forwarding the required ports (80,443, and 5900) through an SSH connection to another server on the same LAN, and browsing localhost (https) on my linux workstation. This works for me:

`ssh -l root -L 80:192.168.0.90:80 -L 443:192.168.0.90:443 -L 5900:192.168.0.90:5900`

But I encounter the "same serial number" error when I try to access different remote machines. I use firefox, and the support documentation describes a procedure to delete an offending certificate at:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Certificate%20contains%20the%20same%20serial%20number%20as%20another%20certificate

The instructions are for an earlier version of firefox than mine, but even after finding the certificate store ( preferences - advanced - certificates - ViewCertificates ) and deleting the 127.0.0.1 entry, closing and reopening the browser, I still get the error.

The only thing that worked for me was to rename away various folders in my home directory where some cached content might linger:

```
mv .cache old.cache
mv .config old.config
mv .mozilla old.mozilla
mv .local old.local
mv .java old.java
```

After this, and closing/reopening my browser, I was able to enter a new security exception to browse localhost. This is of course a rather "blunt-instrument" solution that removes many things besides the offending lingering certificate, but I can put it all back later (after deleting the newly-generated folders). I may try to narrow down which to rename, ".mozilla" would be my first guess.